# Vim, fold Javascript braces and brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, vim

Pretty simple question

Currently I'm using vims fold marker for JavaScript to fold anything between curly braces

```
  autocmd FileType javascript,typescript,json setlocal foldmarker={,}
```

Though often, there's arrays that need be folded as well, but they're wrapped with a pair of `[]`

What regex would I need to tell vim to fold anything between `{}` and `[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `:help 'foldmarker'`:

> The marker is a literal string (a regular expression would be too slow).

As an alternative, you could simply use another `'foldmethod'` like `syntax` or `indent`.

Or try `expr`:

```
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'[\{\[]\\s*$'&&getline(v:lnum+1)=~'^\\s*[\}\]]'?'<1':1
```

(untested)

Comment: Yeah, I figured expression would be the way to go.
Though this expression doesn't seem to work. Might have to tweak it a bit